# Using event handlers on an <embed> tag - other options?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

From my previous question, it was answered that quicktime will capture all of the events in the embed tag. I am using the code below to play a sound clip. I was wondering if there was any other way to handle an onClick? I want to call some javscript onClick.

```
<EMBED src='my_soundfile.wav' type='audio/wav' controls='smallconsole' autostart='false'  onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Audio', 'Play', 'my_soundfile.wav']);"></EMBED>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been thinking about it and came up to a possible solution:

- you use an image instead of embeding the object right away
- on the click of the image:

  - call _gaq.push
  - remove the image from the DOM
  - var embed = document.createElement('embed');
  - set its properties (autostart = true)
  - Append the object embed to it's container

In my opinion it's the only way it will work